# VS 2022 w/Resharper not recognizing syntax in React Scripts

Tags: visual-studio, npm

I'm installing some demo React JS applications. Some of them don't show syntax errors while others do. Am I missing a package in my solution? Or is there a setting in my VS Project that needs set/changed?

Here's a screenshot. The project's package.json is below. The code builds and runs fine with the exception of deprecation warnings, etc. (not important at this point).

[image]

```
{
  "name": "conversations-demo-sdk-update",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "dependencies": {
    "@twilio/conversations": "1.2.0",
    "antd": "^3.26.20",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "ngrok": "^3.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^10.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.6",
    "twilio": "~3.6.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.6.1",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"react-scripts start\" \"node index.js\"",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "keywords": [],
  "description": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being JSX code in JS files. The fix is to enable Resharper's option to allow JSX in JS files.

[Solution found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56391518/1357113)